# Is it possible to unit test factory method doing certificate pinning for retrofit?

Tags: android, junit, mockito, retrofit2, okhttp

For our app, we use an `ApiFactory` to create `Retrofit` clients. The factory methods also take a `List<String>` of host names and a `List<X509Certificate>` which are added to the `OkHttpClient` by a `CertificatePinner`. But these lists can also be `null`. I would like to unit test the part of the factory, when these lists are not `null`. But I have no idea how to test, if a mock certificate is attached to the retrofit interface.

This is what I have so far:

```
@Test
public void testCertificatePinning() {
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(fakeCertString()));
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

        List<X509Certificate> certificates = Collections.singletonList(cert);
        List<String> hostsToSecure = Collections.singletonList("myhost.com");

        ITestFakeApi api = ApiFactory.createRetrofit(ITestFakeApi.class, true, TEST_ENDPOINT, hostsToSecure, certificates);

        /*
        What should I put here?
         */

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private interface ITestFakeApi {

    @GET("/fake/path")
    Call<Void> getFake();

    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/superfake/path")
    Call<Void> getFakeWithHeaders();
}

private String fakeCertString() {
    return  "MIIExDCCA6ygAwIBAgIJAK0JmDc/YXWsMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGcMQswCQYD\n" +
            "VQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UECBMCQVAxDDAKBgNVBAcTA0hZRDEZMBcGA1UEChMQUm9j\n" +
            "a3dlbGwgY29sbGluczEcMBoGA1UECxMTSW5kaWEgRGVzaWduIENlbnRlcjEOMAwG\n" +
            "A1UEAxMFSU1BQ1MxKTAnBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWGmJyYWphbkBSb2Nrd2VsbGNvbGxp\n" +
            "bnMuY29tMB4XDTExMDYxNjE0MTQyM1oXDTEyMDYxNTE0MTQyM1owgZwxCzAJBgNV\n" +
            "BAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJBUDEMMAoGA1UEBxMDSFlEMRkwFwYDVQQKExBSb2Nr\n" +
            "d2VsbCBjb2xsaW5zMRwwGgYDVQQLExNJbmRpYSBEZXNpZ24gQ2VudGVyMQ4wDAYD\n" +
            "VQQDEwVJTUFDUzEpMCcGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYaYnJhamFuQFJvY2t3ZWxsY29sbGlu\n" +
            "cy5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDfjHgUAsbXQFkF\n" +
            "hqv8OTHSzuj+8SKGh49wth3UcH9Nk/YOug7ZvI+tnOcrCZdeG2Ot8Y19Wusf59Y7\n" +
            "q61jSbDWt+7u7P0ylWWcQfCE9IHSiJIaKAklMu2qGB8bFSPqDyVJuWSwcSXEb9C2\n" +
            "xJsabfgJr6mpfWjCOKd58wFprf0RF58pWHyBqBOiZ2U20PKhq8gPJo/pEpcnXTY0\n" +
            "x8bw8LZ3SrrIQZ5WntFKdB7McFKG9yFfEhUamTKOffQ2Y+SDEGVDj3eshF6+Fxgj\n" +
            "8plyg3tZPRLSHh5DR42HTc/35LA52BvjRMWYzrs4nf67gf652pgHh0tFMNMTMgZD\n" +
            "rpTkyts9AgMBAAGjggEFMIIBATAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUG0cLBjouoJPM8dQzKUQCZYNY\n" +
            "y8AwgdEGA1UdIwSByTCBxoAUG0cLBjouoJPM8dQzKUQCZYNYy8ChgaKkgZ8wgZwx\n" +
            "CzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJBUDEMMAoGA1UEBxMDSFlEMRkwFwYDVQQK\n" +
            "ExBSb2Nrd2VsbCBjb2xsaW5zMRwwGgYDVQQLExNJbmRpYSBEZXNpZ24gQ2VudGVy\n" +
            "MQ4wDAYDVQQDEwVJTUFDUzEpMCcGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYaYnJhamFuQFJvY2t3ZWxs\n" +
            "Y29sbGlucy5jb22CCQCtCZg3P2F1rDAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB\n" +
            "BQUAA4IBAQCyYZxEzn7203no9TdhtKDWOFRwzYvY2kZppQ/EpzF+pzh8LdBOebr+\n" +
            "DLRXNh2NIFaEVV0brpQTI4eh6b5j7QyF2UmA6+44zmku9LzS9DQVKGLhIleB436K\n" +
            "ARoWRqxlEK7TF3TauQfaalGH88ZWoDjqqEP/5oWeQ6pr/RChkCHkBSgq6FfGGSLd\n" +
            "ktgFcF0S9U7Ybii/MD+tWMImK8EE3GGgs876yqX/DDhyfW8DfnNZyl35VF/80j/s\n" +
            "0Lj3F7Po1zsaRbQlhOK5rzRVQA2qnsa4IcQBuYqBWiB6XojPgu9PpRSL7ure7sj6\n" +
            "gRQT0OIU5vXzsmhjqKoZ+dBlh1FpSOX2";
}
```

This is the function I want to test, I marked the lines that are not covered yet and need to be covered.

```
public static <T> T createAuthenticatedRetrofit(final Class<T> klass,boolean debugMode, final String endpoint, List<String> hostsToSecure, List<X509Certificate> certificates) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(debugMode);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor,hostsToSecure,certificates);

    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(provideGson()))
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(klass);
}

private static OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor,
    List<String> hostsToSecure,List<X509Certificate> certificates) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // some other config stuff
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
// not under test coverage
    if(certificates != null && !certificates.isEmpty() && hostsToSecure != null && !hostsToSecure.isEmpty()){
        builder.certificatePinner(provideCertificatePinner(hostsToSecure, certificates));
    }
// end
    return builder.build();
}
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to test OkHttp's behavior, which is a 3rd party to you so you shouldn't go about mocking its internals. The fundamental question is why do you want to test the cert pinning? Maybe you should use a higher level test that makes real connections using the pinned certificate.

Comment: For a better understanding I added the method under test. It's the if case that is not covered. Any ideas how I can test this?